# Java - creating new variable with last level of nested lists concatenated

Tags: java, arraylist, data-structures, gson

To retrieve a JSON structure in Java, I'm employing GSON. 
I've created a DataList class to hold a list of list of list of Integers. Why's that? I explain:
I'll use in later in my code dates in pairs (that's a List). I may need to have more than one pair of dates (that's another List). The year, month and day are provided as a List of Integers (last List!).
Like that:

```
...
"$date": [[[2015,3,27],[2015,4,1]]]
...
```

To hold this part of the Json I'm using this variable in my class:

```
public List<List<List<Integer>>> $date = new ArrayList<List<List<Integer>>>();
```

Question: 
How can I transform the $date variable in:

```
public List<List<String>> $dateFORMATED = new ArrayList<List<String>>();
```

Concatenating the last List in a String with always 8 characters? (if date is 2015, 1, 2, it will be "20150102")
Extra: Is it even the best way to handle this problem?

Comment: Are you free to use any JSon structure or are you forced to use that Integer array structure to represent dates ?

Comment: Since this JSON is shared between more than one application, I cannot change it. The idea is also to learn how to handle a concatenation in the last List level, setting it from List<List<List<Integer>>> to another List<List<String>> variable

Answer (score 1):

Your main problem seems to be the creation of a Java `Date` object from an `Integer` Array. That can be handled this way :

```
List<Integer> rawDate;
SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
String stringDate = rawDate.get(2) + "/" + rawDate.get(1) + "/" + rawDate.get(0);
Date date = simpleDateFormat.parse("25/12/2010");
```

**EDIT**

I missread, you really want your date as a String. I must say that I don't quite understand what your are trying to do. Your JSon structure is weird and should be based on objects, not arrays of arrays of arrays of literals.

Anyway, here's a way to do what you want, I guess :

```
String stringDate = rawDate.get(2) + String.format("%02d", rawDate.get(1)) + String.format("%02d", rawDate.get(0));
```

Comment: I got as result something like: Tue Jan 27 00:03:00 BRST 2015, not 20150327 (as String). If it's not too much to ask, how would I also create the new variable $dateFORMATED with the results as I concatenate the values?